# Imaginary line on the Earth is straight or not?

Tags: google-maps

I was watching Google map. Saw a line which is joinging north to south pole. It is going between middle of China and Mexico. But, the line is not straight. Tried to search in net but not able to get anything. Can anyone check and let me know https://www.google.com/maps/@-19.6123649,-178.5132229,3z or http://pichost.org/image/UJKHD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're referring to the International Dateline: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line. If so, no, it isn't straight; there are a few irregularities that have been put in place for various political reasons.

Comment: I read. It tells there are some islands around International Dateline(assuming International dateline is straight. There will be some around both side).  So, it will create confusion having to use different Date in different islands. To avoid that, the line is drawn to cover all island in one side